# Flutter navigation auth middleware

Tags: flutter, routes, middleware, flutter-web, flutter-routes

I have built an application that uses local auth, I want if a user does not use the software for a long time (whether web or mobile app) I can detect it and take it to the password login page.

I try to use `RouteObserver` and I write a custom observer but is not good for navigation, it good for log and track.

[medium](https://medium.com/koahealth/how-to-track-screen-transitions-in-flutter-with-routeobserver-733984a90dea)

I know it's possible to add conditions before all my `Navigator.push()`, but I'm looking for a way to add middleware to all my routes.

Comment: Please see the example.
https://gist.github.com/eduardoflorence/d87978406625a486422d23b77fcd9c16

Comment: thanks a lot for your attention,
the link you sent uses getX for routing, but I use flutter navigator.
@HasibAkon

Answer (score 0):

use `onGenerateRoute` named parameter of 'MaterialApp` Widget.

Comment: Thanks for your response, 
can you provide some code or a simple example?